# Installing a second python environment I’m mac

Tags: python, macos, installation, environment

I’m trying to figure out how to install a second python environment alongside anaconda.

On windows I can just install python in a different folder stand reference the desired python environment using env variables. I’d like to do the same on Mac.
A virtual env won’t do the trick as it does not copy the standard library and other things. It needs to be a complete stand alone environment. I guess I could compile it, but is there an easier way?

Thank you very much for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

It allows you to have several python versions, and even different distributions.

It works, mostly on user space. So, no additional requirements are needed (apart from compilation tools)

Comment: Seems like what I want although it seems the environment will end up in ~/.pyenv. I’ll give it a shot.

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks